# UPATE within UPDATE in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to perform UPDATE-SET-WHERE in nested manner?

E.g. items in table obj_B have the id of items in table obj_A. Perform an update query which first, select and update an item in obj_A then update the corresponding item in obj_B?

```sql
UPDATE obj_A
SET 
obj_A.col1 = "2020-12-12 00:00:00",
obj_A.col2 = "abc"
UPDATE obj_B 
SET
obj_B.col1 = "foo",
obj_B.col2 = "something",
obj_B.time = "2020-12-12 00:00:00"
WHERE obj_B.obj_A_ID = obj_A.id
WHERE obj_A.email = "123@gmail.com" AND obj_A.meta = "456"
```

I know there is a way to produce the identical results (see below) but I am wondering is it possible to perform query recursively.

```sql
UPDATE users, devices
SET 
obj_A.col1 = "2020-12-12 00:00:00",
obj_A.col2 = "abc",
obj_B.col1 = "foo",
obj_B.col2 = "something",
obj_B.time = "2020-12-12 00:00:00"
WHERE obj_A.email = "123@gmail.com" AND obj_A.meta = "456" AND obj_B.obj_A_ID = obj_A.id
```

Comment: Is there any reason why these two updates can't just be run within a single transaction?  I don't really see anything "recursive" about what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Wow, thanks for the quick response. I would like to understand more on how query/statment works programatically am just wondering would it be possible to do it.

Comment: There exists multi-table update.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for the reply. I agree with you which I have updated the question to elaborate more.

Comment: I do not see where the recursion hides in your scheme...

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE    obj_A
LEFT JOIN obj_B ON obj_B.obj_A_ID = obj_A.id
SET obj_A.col1 = "2020-12-12 00:00:00",
    obj_A.col2 = "abc"
    obj_B.col1 = "foo",
    obj_B.col2 = "something",
    obj_B.time = "2020-12-12 00:00:00"
WHERE obj_A.email = "123@gmail.com"
  AND obj_A.meta = "456"
```

?